Can I submit the key member of manifest.json to a public repository?
I've written a browser extension and I want to publish it as open source. Is it safe to submit the manifest.json as is, including the key member?
AFAIK, it is a public key, so there should be no problem with this, but I want to be extra careful with security. Any help is appreciated!

There's no problem, assuming your extension was publicly available in the web store, because this key is exposed in an installed extension on the user's disk, so everyone can see it anyway.

Following @woxxom comment (thank you!), I checked the files of the installed extension and the key was there, on the manifest.json file, so we can assume the key can be submitted to a public repository without any security issues.
